# issue formatting a sql query to only display unique values of 4 tables each containing a different number of results

Tags: sql

i have 4 tables, employees, skills, interests, and goals. im trying to display all skills, interests, and goals for one employee but there a different number of values within each of the skills, interests, and goals tables. so for example employee 1 has 3 interests, 5 skills, and 4 goals. what im trying to do is display 5 rows and 5 columns. column 1 would have the name of employee 1 listed 5 times. column 2 would have the skills of the employee. column 3 would have the interests of the employee with 2 nulls. column 4 would have the goals of the employee with one null. like below

[image]

i have tried a number of different joins but i keep getting all possible combinations as the output.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you add one of the queries that didn't work so we can see what might have gone wrong?

Comment: SELECT 
    employees.first_name,
    skills.skill,
    goals.goal,
    interests.interest
FROM
    employees
        JOIN
    skills ON skills.employee_id = employees.id
        JOIN
    goals ON goals.employee_id = employees.id
        JOIN
    interests ON interests.employee_id = employees.id
WHERE
    employees.first_name LIKE 'will'
;

Comment: Seems like it's somehow defaulting to an outer join? Does it work if you change each JOIN to a LEFT JOIN, or an INNER JOIN?

Comment: oh wait i think i read your question wrong, disregard that

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is an ugly solution, but it works for me, at least in SQL Server:

```
WITH employees_temp as (
  SELECT employees.first_name, row_number() over (ORDER BY id) as RowNum
  FROM employees 
  WHERE employees.first_name LIKE 'will' 
),
skills_temp as (
  SELECT skills.skill, , row_number() over (ORDER BY skills.employee_id) as RowNum
  FROM skills 
  INNER JOIN employees 
  ON skills.employee_id = employees.id 
  WHERE employees.first_name LIKE 'will' 
),
goals_temp as (
  SELECT goals.goal, , row_number() over (ORDER BY goals.employee_id) as RowNum
  FROM goals 
  INNER JOIN employees 
  ON goals.employee_id = employees.id 
  WHERE employees.first_name LIKE 'will' 
),
interests_temp as (
  SELECT interests.interest, , row_number() over (ORDER BY interests.employee_id) as RowNum
  FROM interests 
  INNER JOIN employees 
  ON interests.employee_id = employees.id 
  WHERE employees.first_name LIKE 'will' 
)
select employees_temp.first_name, skills_temp.skill, goals_temp.goal, interests_temp.interest
from employees_temp
full outer join skills_temp
  on employees_temp.RowNum = skills_temp.RowNum
full outer join goals_temp
  on employees_temp.RowNum = goals_temp.RowNum
full outer join interests_temp
  on employees_temp.RowNum = interests_temp.RowNum
```

What this is doing is selecting the data you need for each of the four queries, and adding in a row number. Then, we join all four of those together, joining on the row number. We need a row number to join on, or else it will, as you saw, create every possible combination. The row number functions as a sort of dummy ID for us to join on in order to prevent that.

A couple caveats:

1. You need to be able to do an OUTER JOIN in order for this to work.
2. As a matter of principle, I would filter based on employee ID when possible, rather than pattern matching the first name. This would also simplify the query by removing the need for multiple joins in the first half.
3. If you do so, you're probably best creating a variable at the very beginning of the query to set the employee ID, and then using that variable in the query, so you don't have to update it in multiple places. If that's feasible for the situation you're working in.

Comment: i keep getting the error that 'WITH' is not valid in this position for this server version. i did some looking around and found this page (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90620). i have updated my workbench to the latest version but im still getting the error.

Comment: updated mysql server to the lastest version and i'm no longer getting any errors, however, mysql does not allow full outer joins. with that being said i have tried switching the full outer join with a left join and that only provides me with one row. when i switch it with a right join, i get 3 rows. all of this makes sense as to why i'm getting what i'm getting because there is only 1 employee with the name of 'will' and there are 3 total interests that the employee 'will' has. i'm still racking my brain though on how i can display all of the data associated to the employee 'will'.